# Contoso University part 5, reading related data without passing parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am walking through Contoso University ASP.NET MVC example part 5.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I can't quite understand how the id parameter was passed to the controller/view when I select a course taught by the instructor. 
In the view, the section to display the courses is as following:

```
@if (Model.Courses != null) 
{ 
   <h3>Courses Taught by Selected Instructor</h3> 
<table> 
<tr> 
    <th></th> 
    <th>ID</th> 
    <th>Title</th> 
    <th>Department</th> 
</tr> 

@foreach (var item in Model.Courses) 
{ 
    string selectedRow = ""; 
    if (item.CourseID == ViewBag.CourseID) 
    { 
        selectedRow = "selectedrow"; 
    } 
<tr class="@selectedRow"> 
    <td> 
        *@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { courseID = item.CourseID })*
    </td> 
    <td> 
        @item.CourseID 
    </td> 
    <td> 
        @item.Title 
    </td> 
    <td> 
        @item.Department.Name 
    </td> 
</tr> 
} 

</table>
```

}

The Controller Index function is as following:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? courseID)
    {
        var viewModel = new InstructorIndexData();
        viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors.Include(r => r.OfficeAssignment)
            .Include(r => r.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))
            .OrderBy(i => i.LastName);

        if (id != null)
        {
            ViewBag.InstructorID = id.Value;
            viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(
                i => i.InstructorID == id.Value).Single().Courses;
        }

        if (courseID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Courses = courseID.Value;
            //eager loading
            //viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Courses.Where(
            //    i => i.CourseID == courseID.Value).Single().Enrollments;

            //equivalant, but explicit loading
            var selectedCourse = viewModel.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseID == courseID).Single();
            db.Entry(selectedCourse).Collection(x => x.Enrollments).Load();
            foreach (Enrollment enrollment in selectedCourse.Enrollments)
            {
                db.Entry(enrollment).Reference(x => x.Student).Load();
            }

            viewModel.Enrollments = selectedCourse.Enrollments;
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Why in the ** line of view, I don't have to pass id, as in the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { id= ViewBag.InstructorID,courseID = item.CourseID })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that this is a bit of Asp.net MVC magic at work.  When you perform a postback to the same Controller that your view was parsed from, any previously passed route values are retained by the Razor view engine.  When the page is first loaded, there are no values for either `Id` or `CourseId`.  The first pass back to the Index controller (for the instructor) includes an `Id`, and that `Id` is automatically appended to all calls to the Index Controller from this view.  So the second call, you only have to add the `CourseId` value, since the Id value is already appended to the URL.  You only have to supply an `Id` value if the value is changed, or if you are linking to a different Controller.  You can verify this by manually inspecting the full url that Razor generates on the second link action.